# How can I fetch value from serialize product_options faster

Tags: magento2, database

I am using following query to load data

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `sales_order_item`.`product_options` FROM `magento_giftcardaccount` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `sales_order_item` ON sales_order_item.product_options REGEXP code WHERE (sales_order_item.product_type like 'giftcard' AND main_table.code NOT like '')
```

In magento2

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();
    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    ['sales_order_item' => $this->getTable('sales_order_item')],
    'sales_order_item.product_options REGEXP code',
    ['sales_order_item.product_options']
    )->where("sales_order_item.product_type like 'giftcard' AND main_table.code NOT like ''");

    $this->getSelect()->__toString();
    echo $this->getSelect();die();

    return $this;
}
```

It is taking too long to load, how can I do it faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the function **addFieldToFilter()**

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();

    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['soi' => $this->getTable('sales_order_item')],
        'YOUR CONDITION', //main_table.code = soi.product_type
        ['soi_product_options' => 'soi.product_options']
    );
    $this->addFieldToFilter('soi_product_options', ['like' => '%giftcard%'])
         ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.code', ['nlike' => '']);

    var_dump($this->getSelect()->__toString());die();
}
```

Comment: Not working 'soi_product_options' unknown column

Comment: Okey, what is the main table? and what you want to do exactly !!!

Comment: I solved the error. I tried by using addFieldToFilter() but no difference, still it takes too much time

Comment: Iou have a big data in the tables?

Comment: the data inside product_options are serlize